# символы перед doctype

Tags: php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте! помогите разобраться в чем может быть причина... При загрузке страницы, в начале добавляются "пробелы". 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фрейм - Codeigniter 3, вьюхи пересохранил без BOM, контроллеры проверил на лишний вывод информации, все чисто.... Какую дополнительную информацию я могу предоставить, чтоб было проще разобраться по какой причине может появляться такой глюк? 
Адрес сайта https://nbc.uz.ua/

Comment: Нет у вас там в начале пробелов, а есть куча нулевых байтов в этом спане `<pre id="line1"><span>`

Comment: Я понимаю что это не пробелы.... как убрать нулевые байты, откуда они могут браться?

Comment: Что у вас выводит информацию в `<pre id="line1"><span>`? Потому что нулевые байты в него выводятся + после него еще один доктайп идет правда с экранированными < и >.

Comment: У меня нет даже строки такой во вьюхе. Не знаю откуда может взяться такая строчка "<pre id="line1"><span>"
Я убрал всю динамику, оставил только статический  html....

Comment: Хостер свой баннер вставляет!? :)

Comment: та нееее... ну не так уже))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вижу на сайте у Вас в начале идут нулевые байты (`x00`). Это не BOM.
Попробуйте получить список всех подключенных файлов используя функцию `get_included_files()` (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-included-files.php) и проверьте каждый.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, ушел проверять все 70 файлов)

Comment: Во вьюхе хедера в 16тиричном формате обнаружил возможно лишний символ, файл начинается так "п»ї<!DOCTYPE htm"

Comment: Нулевые байты обнаружил через тоталкоммандер, в файле routes.php
Спасибо за подсказку!